# How to get a text from JTextfield and displaying it on a JTextArea

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to get a text input from a JTextField and displaying it on a JTextField when a button is clicked. Can anyone help please?
I know I am supposed to use getText and setText but not quite sure how I can implement this when the button is clicked. Please have a look at the code below.
Thanks.

```
 import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.util.Random;

        public class CyberPet extends JFrame 
            implements ActionListener {

            private JButton makePetButton,hungryButton, randomButton;
            private JPanel panel;
            private JLabel label, petName, flyLabel;
            private JTextArea responseArea;
            private JTextField textField;
            int x =10;
            int y=10;   
            int xMax = 700;
            int yMax = 500;

            public static void main (String[] args) {
                CyberPet frame = new CyberPet();
                frame.setSize(700, 500);
                frame.createGUI();
                frame.show();
                frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.blue);

            }

            private void createGUI() {
                setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                Container window = getContentPane();
                window.setLayout(new FlowLayout() );

                JPanel buttonGUI = new JPanel();

                panel = new JPanel();
                panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 300));
                panel.setLocation(500, 300);
                panel.setBackground(Color.white);
                panel.setLayout(null);
                window.add(panel);

                buttonGUI = new JPanel();
                buttonGUI.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 100));
                buttonGUI.setLocation(200, 100);
                buttonGUI.setBackground(Color.white);
                window.add(buttonGUI);

                label = new JLabel();
                label.setBackground(Color.white);
                Image img = new ImageIcon (this.getClass().getResource("/frog.gif")).getImage();
                label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));
                label.setLocation(400, 0);
                label.setSize(80, 80);
                panel.add(label);

                flyLabel = new JLabel();
                flyLabel.setBackground(Color.black);
                Image img1 = new ImageIcon (this.getClass().getResource("/fly.gif")).getImage();
                flyLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img1));
                flyLabel.setLocation(10, 10);
                flyLabel.setSize(50, 50);
                panel.add(flyLabel);

                petName = new JLabel("Enter Pet Name!");
                buttonGUI.add(petName);

                textField = new JTextField("");
                textField.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 30));
                textField.setLocation(200, 60);
                textField.addActionListener(this);
                buttonGUI.add(textField);

                makePetButton = new JButton("Make Pet");
                makePetButton.setLocation(160, 60);
                makePetButton.addActionListener(this);
                buttonGUI.add(makePetButton);

                hungryButton = new JButton("Hungry!");
                hungryButton.setLocation(280, 60);
                hungryButton.setSize(100, 30);
                hungryButton.addActionListener(this);
                buttonGUI.add(hungryButton);

                responseArea = new JTextArea("Pet Status");
                buttonGUI.add(responseArea);       


            }
            //   ***** nb line of 4 spaces after insert

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

                //Move down
                 if (event.getSource() == makePetButton)
                    {


                     }

                 //Move Up
                     if (event.getSource() == hungryButton)  
                     {
                    if (y > 10){
                     y=y-20;     
                     label.setLocation(x, y);
                    }
                     }
                 //Makes the Pet
                     if (event.getSource() == makePetButton)
                     {
                     if (x > 10){
                     x=x-20;     
                     label.setLocation(x, y);
                      }
                     }
                 //Move Right
                     if (event.getSource() == textField)
                     {
                     if (x < 280){
                     x=x+20;
                     label.setLocation(x, y);
                        }
                     }
                    //Move random
                     if(event.getSource() == randomButton)
                        {
                         Random rnd = new Random();
                         int xMax = panel.getWidth()-label.getWidth();
                         int yMax = panel.getHeight()-label.getHeight();
                         x = rnd.nextInt(xMax+10);
                         y = rnd.nextInt(yMax+10);
                         label.setLocation(x,y);


                     }
                     }

            }
```

Comment: Don't use a null layout on your panel. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. You can't possibly guess what the size should be for each component. Let the layout manager do its job.

Comment: I disagree I like null layout.

Comment: @JerodHeck: and you'll be out-voted by most all the Swing experts on this site. Null layout often leads to the creation of rigid GUI's, GUI's that might look OK on one specific platform and screen resolution and terrible on many others, GUI's that are quite rigid in structure and that don't lend themselves well to debugging, enhancements or change. For instance try to add one more JRadioButton in the middle of a complex null layout-using GUI would require shifting the positions precisely of many other components. OTOH if you used appropriate layouts, it often requires just one line of code.

Comment: @JerodHeck: often folks who express your opinion are Swing newbies (I don't know of this applies to you or not), and often their opinion is based on a limited knowledge of how to use layout managers effectively. Once you get to know them well, including some of the 3rd party layouts such as MigLayout, I am sure that you'll be singing quite a different tune. In the mean time, you might want to back up your statement as to why you "like" them.

Answer (score 4):

You have the eventHandler, so just call `responseArea.setText(textField.getText())` when handling the click on the appropriate button.

Comment: one plus, but the most important rec for the OP is to read the tutorials as this is all well explained (how to use JButtons, JTextFields, ActionListeners and JTextAreas) there.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: My nipples explode with delight.

Comment: Given that the response area is a JTextArea you would likely use `responseArea.append( textField.getText() )`.

Comment: Thanks @MarcusMüller, I used your method and it work!!

Comment: Hi guys, I managed to append the responseArea to the textField. I wanted to know if using imageIcon can allow me to draw the images on my panel only when the makePet button is pressed and a name is given it to. Thanks